# django-parler свои языки

Tags: django, django-admin, django-rest-framework

подскажите пожалуйста, как в django-parler добавить язык, которого нет в списке доступных? Спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [django-parler языки в админке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/916115/django-parler-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Comment: Нет, там вопрос о отображении языков в админке, а этот о добавлении кастомного языка